# As of 2018, is there a way for browsers to get data about the users hardware?

Tags: browser, hardware

Most questions about this topic ask "How can I use language X or library Y to get hardware information".

I want to know if this is possible AT ALL using only a browser without installing third party .exe's which are scary for most people and today are automatically labelled as "dangerous" by chrome.

Obviously i'd prefer not to use extensions, but if its possible using extensions, i'd like to know.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, no, you cannot get direct hardware information on a user for security reasons, and this is unlikely to change as it would be a serious privacy issue (specific hardware could be used to uniquely identify specific users).

You can get some limited information though, like the OS type, version, and architecture found in the user agent string and `navigator.platform`. You can also feature-detect certain functionality like touch screens, or WebGL graphics card comparability.

Generally, your webpages shouldn't need to know information about a user's hardware, and should "just work" on a variety of hardware, even hardware you don't know about or has yet to be invented. If there is something specific you think you need to detect, I'd recommend asking a specific question about that feature.

Comment: I would like to build something like "can I run it" (https://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri) web app but without the extra step of downloading third part exe to determine the user's specs.